# Looping through multi dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

## Edit

The approach taken here was completely wrong. This is how it should have been done.

```cs
public class Recipe {
  public List<string> ingredients;
  public string result;

  public Recipe (List<string> _ingredients, string _result) {
    this.ingredients _ingredients;
    this.result = _result;
  }
}
```

And then when looping:

```
Recipe[] recipes = new Recipe[] {
  new Recipe(new List<string>(new string[] { "potato", "tabasco" }), "explosivePotato"),
  new Recipe(new List<string>(new string[] { "mentos", "cola" }), "colaCannon"),
  new Recipe(new List<string>(new string[] { "potato", "cola" }), "potatoCola"),
  new Recipe(new List<string>(new string[] { "potato", "chips" }), "potatoChips")
}
```

This would also mean that looping would be a whole lot simpler.

---

## Original question

I have a C# script with the following array:

```
string[,] craftingRecipes = new string[,]{
    // {recipe},{result}
    {"potato","tabasco"},{"explosivePotato"},
    {"mentos","cola"},{"colaCannon"},
    {"potato","cola"},{"potatoCola"},
    {"potato","chips"},{"potatoChips"}
};
```

How can i loop through every item in the n'th subarray? So for example the array containing `{"potato","tabasco"}` should be looped twice, since there are two items in it.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your sample does not compile, so hard to see what "n'th subarray" should be... Please show sample that compiles or better yet consider using list of strongly typed objects (like `Recipe { List<string> Components; string Result;}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per the edit 19-09-2018, this can now be properly answered.

Iterate over the array using two simple nested `foreach` loops.

```cs
foreach (Recipe recipe in recipes) {
  System.Console.Write("To make '{0}' you need:", recipe.result);

  foreach (ingredient in recipe.ingredients) {
    System.Console.Write(ingredient);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your question, since your code doesn't compile, but you can use this loop to iterate through items in first "line":

```
        int line = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < craftingRecipes.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(craftingRecipes[line,i]);
        }
```

Although, Your `array` should look more like this (I had to add `sth_missing_here`, because `Multi-Dimensional Array` must have sub-arrays with the same length):

```
        string[,] craftingRecipes = new string[,]{
            {"potato","tabasco"},{"explosivePotato","sth_missing_here_1"},
            {"mentos","cola"},{"colaCannon","sth_missing_here_2"},
            {"potato","cola"},{"potatoCola","sth_missing_here_3"},
            {"potato","chips"},{"potatoChips","sth_missing_here_3"}
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OfType<T>` method, to convert the multidimensional array into an `IEnumerable<T>` result, for sample:

```
IEnumerable<string> items = craftingRecipes.OfType<int>();

foreach(var item in items)
{
   // loop between all elements...
}
```